# Generic Scanner Driver for windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, drivers, scanner

I have a scanner UMAX astar 5600. The scanner stopped working after I upgraded to windows 10 from windows 7.

I managed to make the scanner work again by making use of Samsung scanner drivers(As suggested in a YouTube video).

Things worked great, but now that driver of the Samsung scanner is not available, so my scanner does not work.

The device shows up in the **device manager** as "USB Scanner" wah an yellow exclamation mark. I am unable to add the device under **devices and printers.**

Is there a generic windows driver that I can use.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No drivers to be found. I can only find [VueScan](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/umax.html) which might work. This is a commercial software, so perhaps buying a new scanner will be more economical.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14088/windows-10-install-and-use-a-scanner

Comment: https://paperscan-scanner-software-free-edition.windows10compatible.com/

Comment: You can find my solutions reading the answers to a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1503774/find-a-driver-for-epson-perfection-1240u-photo-scanner-on-windows-10-64-bit/1530771#1530771).

Answer (score 0):

Selecting **Microsoft > USB scanner device** for the driver has got the scanner working.

The USB scanner device listed under Microsoft seems to be the generic scanner driver I was looking for.

Selecting that driver for my scanner make it to work like a charm.

Comment: More detail in your answer is needed, otherwise it is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Windows solution, but Linux has a generic scanner driver in its kernel, and it is not hard to use at all if you can reboot your machine.

You may download liveOS (no installation needed) from Fedora or Ubuntu, write the image on a usb drive by rufus.ie , and reboot your PC with the usb drive.

The liveOS even contains a "Simple Scan" tool that acts as the GUI. However, you may need a second USB drive (or to access a network drive) to save the scanned documents.

Answer (score 0):

I have VueScan and it works great, had old Canon scanner, then I and bought a used Fujitsu ScanSnap scanner and VueScan works with it, it even scans both sides of the paper in one pass. The only problem is the scanner won't work on USB3 connections, I don't know if it's a problem with the program or the scanner.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1181500)