# Find a driver for Epson Perfection 1240U Photo scanner on Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: windows-10, drivers, 64-bit, scanner

Epson doesn't officially support this scanner under Win10 64 bit. What to do?
After searching around I found the solution myself. Please see below.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution [here](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/18767-how-install-old-epson-perfection-1200-scanner-windows-10-a.html).

(translated the following steps from german. Sorry if it's not exactly translated.)

- Search the Win10 64 bit driver for the Epson Perfection 2400 scanner
- I found "Epson Scan 3.0.4 17-Jul-2009 20.68MBs" and installed it. The installer asks for the scanner model. I only selected EPSON Perfection 2400.
- Connecting the scanner afterwards needs some manual help: Go to device manager and find the EPSON Perfection 1240. Manually install the driver from the context menu - Update driver... - Browse my computer... - Let me pick from a list...
- Select Imaging devices
- EPSON Perfection 2400
- Done

The scanner is shown as EPSON Perfection 2400 instead of EPSON Perfection 1240. But it works.

On the german epson support page there is also an update for the driver "EPSON Scan Updater 1.0 13-Jul-2018 0.72MBs". I also installed this afterwards with success.
Probably the english version "Scanner Driver and EPSON Scan Utility v3.04A" has this update already included.

Comment: Still working after feature update to Windows 10 Version 1909, Build 18363.657

Comment: The driver for 2400 seems to be no longer available on the Epson web site.

Comment: @AlexanderVorobiev: You can get it [here from my proton drive](https://drive.proton.me/urls/D8Z7WX5XCG#lRElMAr5CXCA). The link is valid until Nov 5, 2023.
It contains the Epson Scan (epson324500eu_EPSON_Scan.zip) and an update (epson630619eu_EPSON_ScanUpdater_1_0.zip)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the files!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but a workaround that could very well be thwarted with some next upgrade of Windows 10.

There are two better working alternatives :

1) Install [VueScan Standard/Professional](https://www.hamrick.com/), as they have reverse-engineered the old driver and made it to work in Windows 10. However, this solution is not free.

2) Install the [old drivers](https://www.driversdownloader.com/download/epson/epson10609.exe.html) under Windows XP as a virtual machine in [VMware Workstation Player](https://www.vmware.com/), which is free for non-commercial purposes.
If you have (or find) a working key then the ISO file of Windows XP Pro can be downloaded from [here](https://archive.org/download/WinXPProSP3x86).

I also installed an old registered Windows XP version of VueScan Professional in this VM to scan the images. This works fine and scans faster 
than the trial version of the most recent VueScan Standard/Pro which supports Windows 10.

This way you can still use ANY old USB hardware no longer supported in Windows 10 on your computer... with Windows 10 ;-)